# Can Wands trigger the effect of "Insightful Divination"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items, feats, divination

The feat Insightful Divination gives you a bonus on initiative whenever you use a divination spell. Does casting a spell via the use of a spell-trigger item, such as a wand or a scroll, count for the purposes of this feat, and thus bestow the aforementioned bonus on the caster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

From Insightful Divination:

> When you cast a divination spell

<sup>(*Complete Mage* pg. 44)</sup>

From the [rules on wands](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wands.htm):

> Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so **casting a spell from a wand** is usually a standard action that doesn’t provoke attacks of opportunity.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

When you use a wand, you *cast* that spell. With Insightful Divination, when you *cast* a divination, you gain some bonuses. That includes casting from a wand.